# Is the Cantonese diminutive (粒) the same as the Mandarin (子)?

Tags: usage, characters, cantonese, topolect

Is the Cantonese diminutive (粒) as in 鸡粒炒饭 the same as the Mandarin (子)? Is that the right character to use?

UPDATE: Sorry for the mistake, I really did mean 粒, not 里.

Comment: Sorry, I added and then removed an image. http://b.share.photo.xuite.net/r8susan/1b0d43d/2509274/112699491_m.jpg I looked up the vendor name (好Wellcome) and that seems to be Taiwanese, not from Hong Kong, so the image was irrelevant as an illustration of usage in HK or Cantonese speaking areas.

Comment: Adam Sheik's Cantodict does not seem to confirm this usage of 雞里 or 里.

Comment: Doesn't actually 里 come from 裡肌 or 里肌 ([tender]loin, or other section of animal meat)? Because 鸡里脊 is 'chicken fillet', and if you search for images, that's what it looks like.

Comment: I am a Cantonese native speaker and I haven't been acknowledged that 里 is diminutive! It should be 雞粒炒飯

Comment: Basically 粒 = 丁

Comment: Is it the same 丁 as in 苦丁茶？

Comment: If you could explain it a bit you could make it an answer and I could accept it.

Comment: According to Babelcarp the 丁 in 苦丁茶 means manly like 男丁、壮丁. I'm not sure where they got that from, or if it's correct or not. http://jk.hecha.cn/info/7/show_23391.html gives this explanation: 苦丁茶是什么?苦丁茶(Ilex kudingcha C. J. Tseng)又叫万承茶、一叶青等，顾名思义，“苦”就是指其味甘苦，“丁”就是“一丁点”的意思，苦丁茶的意思就是“有一点苦的茶”。Which makes sense too, especially since the tea is Sichuanese and “丁”就是“一丁点”的意思 makes perfect sense in Sichuanese. In which case 丁点的丁 and 肉丁 could very well be the same! This is all speculation though.

Comment: Strictly speaking, 雞丁 is bigger than 雞粒 in size ..... but people tends not to distinguish them anymore.

Comment: And 雞子 means chicken testicles   :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

“鸡粒” is common Chinese, means "diced chicken", “粒” means diced small cubes of meat.

“鸡子” is Cantonese, means the kidney, a viscera of chicken.

Actually different things. But “鸡粒”, “鸡籽”, and “鸡子” may all mean the egg of chicken in loosely.

Comment: 雞子 means chicken testicles :P

Comment: We have 「雞粒」in Cantonese for quite a long time.

Comment: I see, I'd say it's common Chinese, not Cantonese unique.

Comment: @HenryHO Well~ That's it... I think I know the difference...

Answer (score -1):

the meanings of those two are the same in the only single word,but we'd like to use the specific one in some established by usage phrases.